# Iphone - App ID and in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

I have an iPhone application in the store that has in-app purchases. This app has an app ID in the system that is, lets say,

com.acme.myApp

I am about to create an iPad version of it. I have duplicate the target on Xcode, but after duplicating, I see Xcode has not changed the identifier for the new target, that is still com.acme.myApp, subtly suggesting that I can have two targets with the same identification, even each target being a different app.

My question is: is it possible to have an iPhone and an iPad release with the same identifier? If so, can I use the same in-apps already created on iTunes connect for the iPhone version for ipad's?

I suspect I will have to create another app ID for this new version, create new provisioning profiles based on that and create again all zillions of in-app purchases I have for the iPhone version, for this new ipad version, right?

What do you guys think?

Comment: i believe your answer is a yes, not 100% sure but i did realize that before 5.0 you could build a Iphone app and Ipad app with the same Target.

Comment: ok, but that would be a universal all, not two apps. So, this must be one more bug of Xcode 4, that BTW, I hate.

Comment: yeah,I'm not particularly a big fan either but i would say to be safe to go ahead and build two separate targets for each.

Comment: ok, thanks. If you can post this as an answer I can accept it... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode in older versions would build a folder for both Iphone and Ipad now in the newer versions i have not seen this.

But as you did mention its for two separate applications and using the same target....Now that i don't believe will work, the best bet in the situation outlined above would be to build two separate targets for each.